# Flutter firebase: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try to update a collection in Firestore and I receive this error on the screen, although the the collection updates perfectly.

[image: Error message]

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("MyCollection")
  .doc(widget.selectedItem["UID"]) // this doc is gotten from a previous Screen using listView
  .collection("MySubCollection")
  .doc(UID)// this is the current userID which I defined earlier
  .update({"Pay": "Paid", "ChatID": chatId});//I have also defined chatId as DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
```

PS: I also tried to use `widget.selectedItem?["UID"]` instead, but it still gives me this error

Comment: It looks like `widget.selectedItem` is null. Using a question mark doesn't change anything about that, you can't call `["UID"]` on `null`.

Comment: How do I call ["UID"] on null. Can you help, please

Comment: You can't make any call on `null`. You'll need to figure out why your `widget.selectedItem` is null. Set a breakpoint on that line, run in the debugger, and see where your assumption that `widget.selectedItem` would not be `null` is falling apart.